# Permutation in group theory

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am confuse how to proceed for the following question. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance!

For a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, one say that $k$ is a fixed point of $\pi$ if and only if $\pi(k)=k$. What is the number of permutations in $S_5$ having exactly one fixed point?

Comment: 18th ques no. In this pic

Comment: I can barely read what is written, is it $S_9$? The picture is really blurry. Please make the effort to retype the question and show your progress or thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Sorry @falcon for a permutation π of {1,2,3.....n} we say that k is fixed if π(k)=k then number of permutations in S5 having exactly one fixed point is now pls solve this

Comment: Hint: Do you know about derangements?  Say $\pi(x) = x$ and $\pi$ fixes no other point.  Then if we throw out $x$, $\pi$ becomes a derangement.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ is a fixed point, all the other symbols must be moved. This is same as the number of derangements on four symbols and hence 9 in number. Thus the total number of permutations with exactly one fixed point is $9 \times 5 = 45$. If we want the number of permutations in $S_n$ with exactly one fixed point, then it is 
\begin{equation*}
 n! \left(1- \frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\cdots + (-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right) 
\end{equation*}

Comment: An instance of the inclusion-exclusion principle!

Answer (score 1):

There are $5$ possible fixed points, but we also need that no other point is fixed, so the answer will 5 times the number of permutations of $4$ elements without fixed points. Such permutations in $S_4$ will have to be a union of cycles of length at least $2$: $(ab)(cd)$ and $(abcd)$. In the former case, we may assume $a=1$, and then there are $3$ possibilities for $b$. In the latter case, we also have $a=1$ and then there are 6 ways to arrange $\{2,3,4\}$ as $bcd$. So there are $9$ total fixed point free $4$ element permutations. Thus the answer is $5*9=45$.

Answer (score 1):

In $S_5$, a permutation will have one of the following cycle types (these are also the conjugacy classes of $S_5$):

- identity $1$
- transposition $(1,2)$
- double transposition $(1,2)(3,4)$
- $3$-cycle $(1,2,3)$
- $4$-cycle $(1,2,3,4)$
- $5$-cycle $(1,2,3,4,5)$
- disjoint $2$-cycle and $3$-cycle $(1,2)(3,4,5)$

The only cycle types that fix exactly one number are the double transpositions and the $4$-cycles. So the answer would be #{double transpositions in $S_5$} + #{$4$-cycles in $S_5$}

Answer (score 1):

We want to find the number of permutations in $S_5$ having exactly one fixed point.  This is the number of permutations of shape $(a)(bcde)$ or $(a)(bc)(de)$.  The number of permutations having the first shape is $5 \times 3! = 30$, and the number of permutations having the second shape is $5 \times 3 = 15$, for a total of $45$ permutations.